# Get the user id of a username identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

MVC 5 with asp.net identity 2.0

I understand how to get the currently logged in user id.  I have a need to get the user id of a different user in the system.  How is this done?

Ex.  I need to get the user id of user names "fsmith" ...

Comment: For this issue, I am actually in a different controller - not the account controller.  How do you get the user manager context from a different controller?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Inside the AccountController you can call the following method to get user object and then get the User Id.

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
var userId = user.Id;
```

If you are not inside AccountController you can get the UserManager reference using the following code

```
var UserManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

Comment: Ok - getting closer.  I have the user manager reference.  Now I am getting an error in the IDE saying something about the await needing an async method, etc.

Comment: You could just call the synchronous method as follows

`var user = UserManager.FindByName(userName);`

Alternately, you can make your Controller action an Async method using the following convetion.

`public async Task<YourMethodReturnValue> YourControllerAction(...)`

Check out about async await usage.

Answer (score 4):

To add to Shashi's useful answer...

If you're inside the account controller you can use the existing UserManager:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
var userId = user.Id;
```

In other controllers (and maybe select other places where HttpContext is available) you create a User Manager with:

```
var um = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

But what it took me a while to realize is you can get at it just about anywhere with this last bit. For instance I used it in my seed method (in Configuration.cs) so I could seed the User property of another model:

```
var um = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(*insert-your-db-context-here*));
```

Comment: This is the more accurate answer.

Answer (score 2):

One way would to use the [FindByNameAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497543(v=vs.108).aspx) method of your user manager (or the generic version of it). It takes the name of the user (in your case "fsmith") and returns a task of a user object. This user object contains all the information available about that user.

A code snippet could look similar to the following one (if you're looking for the database ID):

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync("fsmith");
var userId = user.Id;
```

**EDIT**

The UserManager instance is normally declared as follows (keep in mind that there are many ways of declaring it, for example when using Dependency Injection):

```
public AccountController()
  : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
{
}

public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
  UserManager = userManager;
}

public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }
```

Comment: See the edit in my post. When using the Visual Studio template you should find the declaration inside your **AccountController**.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bearing Token Auth, the above sample do not return an Application User.

Instead, use this:

```
ClaimsPrincipal currentUser = this.User;
var currentUserName = currentUser.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(currentUserName);
return user.Id;
```

This works in apsnetcore 2.0.  Have not tried in earlier versions.